# CSS - Clip path svg not working on firefox

Tags: css, svg, mask, clip, clip-path

I'm trying to use clip path but this is not working on firefox.
I already search about this and i found this code in stack overflow.
I have several shapes implemented but this is just work in chrome and safari.

```css
.shape
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  -moz-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
  background-color: $page-title-background-green;


}
img
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 296px;
  height: 296px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  -moz-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points=".15 0, .7 0, 1 .5, .7 1, .15 1, 0 .7, .2 .5, 0 .3"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="shape">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/600/400/">
</div>
```

How can i solve that?

Thank's

Comment: Is yur CSS embedded in your webpage or is it a separate CSS file. If it's a separate file then #clipper is actually short for <this file>#clipper and your CSS file does not contain anything with an id of clipper (it's in the html file).

Comment: my css are in a separate file. Where put the name of the file? in the css? Thank's @Robert Longson

Comment: url(whatever your html file name is.html#clipper)

Comment: i try what you said but this not work. @Robert Longson

Comment: Is the CSS file in the same directory as the html file? If not you'll need to put a relative path in.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```html
    <body>
        <svg class="svg-defs">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clipping">
                  <polygon points="98.4999978 153.75 38.2520165 185.424245 49.7583542 118.337123 1.01670635 70.8257603 68.3760155 61.037872 98.5000012 1.1379786e-14 128.624005 61.0378871 195.98331 70.8258091 147.241642 118.337136 158.747982 185.424247"></polygon>
                </clipPath>
           </defs>
        </svg>
        <svg width="200" height="300">
          <style type="text/css" media="screen">
              image {
                  clip-path: url(#clipping);
              }
          </style>
          <image xlink:href="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5607/5091629.6b/0_612e6_b9039c0d_M.jpg" width="200" height="300" />
        </svg>
    </body>
```

So, try to set the **style** inside your SVG element, or give a style attribute to **image**, like this:

```
<image style="clip-path: url(#clipping);" xlink:href="...">
```